# How-to sort date with different field name (and retrieve field name)?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, date, templates, meteor

I'm using: Meteor, JS and mongoDB.

Let's say I have a document like this:

```
document {
   field 'a' : date(01/03/2016),
   field 'b' : date(13/45/2015),
   field 'c' : date(23/01/1987),
   field 'd' : date(17/09/2000),
   field 'e' : "hello"
}
```

I want to 'sort' in a template (html using spacebar) this:

```
23/01/1987 - the name I give to 'c'
17/09/2000 - Another name I give to 'd'
13/45/2015 - name of 'b'
01/03/2016 - name of 'a'
```

I've literally no idea how to do so.

I'm - of course - able to sort by 'date' but how to retrieve the 'field name' (in front of the right date)?

I heard about 'associative array'...
Any clue, please?

Comment: Can you edit your question to use actual JS notation to show your sample document?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default functionality for it in Blaze. So, you should use custom helper for this like:

```
const fieldCaptionMap = {
  a: 'My field a',
  b: 'Field b',
  c: 'Anouther field c'
};

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  yourDocument() {
    return {
      a: new Date('2016-01-02'),
      b: new Date('2016-02-03'),
      c: new Date('2016-03-04')
    }
  },
  sortDocumentDates(doc) {
    return Object.keys(doc)
      .filter(key => _.isDate(doc[key]))
      .map(dateKey => {
        return {
          field: dateKey,
          date: doc[dateKey],
          caption: fieldCaptionMap[dateKey]
        };
      })
      .sort((entryA, entryB)=> {
        return entryA.date.getTime() - entryB.date.getTime();
      });
  }
});
```

Then your template will look like:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    <ul>
        {{#each sortDocumentDates yourDocument}}
            <li>{{date}} - {{caption}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

I am not sure why you need structure like that, but if you are going to keep some sort of history in your document, then easier to maintain structure is something like:

```
const myDocument = {
  history: [
    {
      date: new Date('2016-01-02'),
      action: 'documentCreate'
    },
    {
      date: new Date('2016-01-03'),
      action: 'documentUpdate'
    },
    {
      date: new Date('2016-01-03'),
      action: 'documentArchive'
    }
  ]
  //other document fields ...
};
```

Comment: With some delay.. Sorry... and Thank you very much.
Your second idea `history : [...]` is brilliant, super simple but brilliant. I didn't think about it one second...

My problem now is: if my imported `history.date` is `empty` then Mongodb writes that the date is EPOCH, whereas I'd prefer something like `null`.... But, if I succeed in doing so (how?), then, for `array[0]`, I would have `date: null` and `action:something`, and then `$addToSet` (in MongoDB) won't update anymore if I have a real date for `array[0]` (like 12/12/2016)... Any idea? Thank you very much, again!

Comment: I am not sure I understand you.